# how may be the virtual memore be limited in linux

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine in which every process can only malloc most 128M memory。
and when I typed "ulimit -v" in the teminal, is display 131072 while in the other machine is "ulimited".
Can any one tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to ask the person who set that machine up.

There is file `/etc/security/limits.conf` that sets the default limits.

Comment: the limits.conf does not set the virtual memory~~

Comment: @binbin then `grep -r 131072 /etc` and see if anything else might set it.